# data is not transferring at the right time in my prepare for segue function

Tags: swift, segue, collectionview

here is my code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Get Cell Label
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! monthTableViewCell!;

    valueToPass = (currentCell?.monthOutlet.text)!
    print(valueToPass)



}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "toMonthVC") {

        // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
        let viewController = segue.destination as! monthCellViewController
        // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
        viewController.dataFromHoursVC = valueToPass
    }
}
```

So basically I am trying to pass a value from one VC to another. the didSelectRow is working perfectly how expected. However, the prepare function is running late. For example, the first time the code is run, the second vc sees the passed value as nil. But when i go back and then do it again, it says the passed value, but the value is the one that was done before. So simply put it is acting like the prepare function is behind or being called late.

Comment: Could you show your declaration of `valueToPass`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the prepareforswgue being called late, because whenever you tap the back button the view is deleted and is created again the second time. Please show some more to know what is really happening

Comment: Where exactly are you accessing the `dataFromHoursVC` variable in your `monthCellViewController` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you set up your segue? It sounds like the value isn't being set before the segue is performed.

Try doing it this way:

[image]

After you give your segue an identification name set up your code like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   // Get Cell Label
   let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
   let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! monthTableViewCell!;

   valueToPass = (currentCell?.monthOutlet.text)!
   print(valueToPass)

   // invoke the segue manually after value is set
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SEGUEID", sender: self)
}
```

**Quick Warning**

You really should be careful using force unwraps `optionalVar!` and force downcasts `thing = otherThing as! Type`. It's far better to always use if-let and guard-let statements or fail-able down casts `as?`. Using these will decrease the chances of developing a hard to find nil value bug.

Comment: This answer fixed the issue. What i did was i created a segue between the cell and second view controller rather than the way you showed above. So i went back and did what you did and everything works perfectly now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you set your tableview's data source and/or delegate to you view controller in interface builder.  Depending on the rest of your code, initialization of the view controller may need to access the tableview's delegate or dataSource during initialization (i.e. before the controller is passed to the prepareForSegue function).  When it is set in IB, the delegate (or dataSource) allow the functions to be called.